# Set a camera in quicktime using applescript

Tags: macos, camera, applescript, quicktime, recording

I know there is probably a very simple answer to this. I'm trying to setup an Applescript application that when activated will launch quicktime, open a new movie recording, set the camera and audio, start the recording and then end the recording and save it after 30 seconds.

I currently have a script that is doing everything except setting the camera and audio source. Any tips on how to select a certain camera and audio source using applescript?

Thanks!

Here is the code as it stands now..

```
--Set some Variables

--Max length of recording
set maxrec to 20 --in seconds

--Ending Message
set EndMsg to "Thank you for participating in this project. Your video has been recorded."


--Begin Loop
repeat
--Get the person's name
repeat
    display dialog "What's your name?" default answer ""
    set theName to (text returned of result)
    if theName ≠ "" then exit repeat
end repeat

--Set the date
set theDate to current date
set y to text -4 thru -1 of ("0000" & (year of theDate))
set m to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & ((month of theDate) as integer))
set d to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & (day of theDate))
set h to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & (hours of theDate))
set mm to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & (minutes of theDate))
set dateStamp to (y & "-" & m & "-" & d & " " & h & mm as string)

--Create a folder for the person
tell application "Finder"
    set p to path to movies folder from user domain
    try
        make new folder at p with properties {name:"Video Clips"}
    end try
    set p to (path to movies folder from user domain as text) & "Video Clips:"
    make new folder at p with properties {name:dateStamp & " " & theName}
    set thePath to result

    --Establish the final name of the movie
    set fileName to ((thePath as text) & dateStamp & ".mov" as string)
end tell

--Open New Recording, start and stop it
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set newMovieRecording to new movie recording
    set windowID to id of first window whose name = "Movie Recording"
    delay 2
    tell newMovieRecording
        --Set Camera to Blackmagic
        set current camera of newMovieRecording to Blackmagic of video recording devices
        start
    end tell
    set theSeconds to maxrec
    repeat theSeconds times
        display dialog theSeconds buttons {} giving up after 1 with title "REMAINING TIME"
        set theSeconds to (theSeconds - 1)
    end repeat
    tell newMovieRecording
        stop
    end tell

    --save and close the recording  
    set newMovieRecordingDoc to first document whose name = (get name of first window whose id = windowID)
    tell newMovieRecordingDoc to save in fileName
    set SavedRecordingDoc to first document whose name = (get name of first window whose id = windowID)
    tell SavedRecordingDoc to close
    quit

end tell

--Display "Thank You" Message
tell application "System Events" to set frontmost of process "Video Booth" to true
display dialog EndMsg giving up after 20 buttons {"Continue…"} ¬
    default button 1
end repeat
```

Here is the error I get right now when I run it.

error "QuickTime Player got an error: Can’t make Blackmagic of every video recording device of document \"Movie Recording\" into type specifier." number -1700 from Blackmagic of every video recording device of document "Movie Recording" to specifier

Comment: I'm intrigued by this line:         set current camera of newMovieRecording to Blackmagic of video recording devices
Where is 'Blackmagic' defined? I tried replacing that with a string containing the name of my iPhone, and got 'Access not allowed'.

Answer (score 2):

use the `current camera` and `current microphone` properties of your movie recording object. Just replace item 1 with the appropriate device:

```
set current camera of recording to item 1 of video recording devices
set current microphone of recording to item 1 of audio recording devices
```

Comment: Hey, So I tried some of your code and got an error. I've edited my original question to show my full script with the bit of code from you that I added in and the error. Let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: view `video recording devices` in another script and pick from the list of devices by using item 1, item 2, item 3, etc. I couldn't figure out how to specify the devices directly, but this does the job.

Comment: So I tried the code exactly as you have it and I still get the error "Result:
error "Can’t get every video recording device of missing value." number -1728 from every «class vdev» of missing value".

Comment: Move it out of "tell newMovieRecording" or get rid of "of newMovieRecording" from the code I gave you

Comment: This doesn't work for me in ElCap: I set current camera of newRecording to video recording device deviceIndex, but the movie just uses whatever camera I left it with last time I manually changed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had accomplished this by doing it manually

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "QuickTime Player"
    #To open dialog to show available cameras
    click button 3 of window 1
    #To select our device
    click menu item "your_camera_name" of menu 1 of button 3 of window 1
end tell
```

With this the dialog will open and you will select your camera from the list...

Taken from another answer I made:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45454785/3685973