# Getting osascript to work with iPhone and QuickTime Player

Tags: applescript

I run this script and applescript can detect the devices just fine

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    video recording devices
end tell
```

It gives a the reply below

```
{screen compression preset "FaceTime HD Camera" of application "QuickTime Player", screen compression preset "Gangzheng's iPhone" of application "QuickTime Player"}
```

But when I run my actual script

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    video recording devices
    set newMovieRecording to new movie recording
    tell newMovieRecording
        set current camera of newMovieRecording to "Gangzheng's iPhone"
        set current microphone of newMovieRecording to "Gangzheng's iPhone"
        start
    end tell
end tell
```

it says `QuickTime Player got an error: Can’t make "Gangzheng's iPhone" into type video recording device.`

Is there a way to make applescript record anything from iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had accomplished what you want to do, but in a different way because I also tried with

```
set current camera of newMovieRecording to "Gangzheng's iPhone"
```

but had no luck.... So here is my script for setting a camera

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "QuickTime Player"
    #Set volume to 100%
    click button 1 of window 1
    #To open dialog to show available cameras
    click button 3 of window 1
    #To select our device
    click menu item "Gangzheng's iPhone" of menu 1 of button 3 of window 1
end tell
```

My script was a bit longer because I wanted to record the screen of my iphone at my MAC... So I had to set QuickTime Player to full screen, move mouse pointer outside the screen and so on...

```
tell application "Finder"
    set bigBounds to (get bounds of window of desktop)
end tell
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    start
    #Start new recording cmd + option + N
    tell application "System Events" to key code 45 using {option down, command down}
    set iBounds to (get bounds of front window) 
    if bigBounds = iBounds then
        delay 1 
    else
        #Full screen only if is not already at full screen control + cmd + F        
        tell application "System Events" to key code 3 using {control down, command down}
        delay 1 
    end if
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "QuickTime Player"                 
        #Set volume to 100%
        click button 1 of window 1      
        #To open dialog to show available cameras
        click button 3 of window 1      
        #To select our device
        click menu item "iPhone de User" of menu 1 of button 3 of window 1  
    end tell
    #To move mouse to the right side of the screen
    set mouseToolsPath to "/Users/Shared/MouseTools"
    set x to (item 3 of bigBounds) - 1
    set y to (item 4 of bigBounds) / 2
    #Por si el archivo no existe...
    try
        do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (x as text) & " -y " & (y as text)
    on error errMsg number errNum
        display dialog "An unknown error occurred:  " & errNum as text
    end try
end tell
```

Hope it is helpful to someone.

Comment: I take that as a solution as I can see the dropdown and the phone option has been chosen. But it does not record the video

Answer (score 0):

barbudito, can you try this?

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    get video recording device "Gangzheng's iPhone"
    set newMovieRecording to new movie recording
    tell newMovieRecording
        start
        delay 10
        do shell script "env"
        pause
        save newMovieRecording in "/Users/pmlg673f/Movies/test.mov"
        stop
        close newMovieRecording
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this exact problem and made the following blog post which covers how I solved it https://kevinjalbert.com/applescript-that-mirrors-iphone-to-quicktime/. I had used some inspiration from this post and others as I looked around for a way to set the video/audio inputs via AppleScript.

The source for the AppleScript is here: https://gist.github.com/kevinjalbert/d7661a6a34c1d66dccf701f64eb09be4#file-mirror-scpt.